# With Statement inside functions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

So I can't get the code inside the function 'Display_File' to run. All it does is yell about bad indentation, too much, or not enough. I've tried every indentation possible and nothing works. I'm assuming I can't use a with statement inside a function. I use that code outside of the function and it works fantastic.

Just trying to open a CSV file, remove some of garbage above the headers and load that into a text box, and eventually making a chart with the data after I can at least get the data displayed correctly in the GUI. I tried putting the display file code into the open file code but didn't work there so I figured it need its own function. I don't care where it is, long as the bloody thing works.

Some code isn't there yet to do some of what I mentioned. I just need that to run without yelling about something and I'll be happy.

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

#Create GUI Window
app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('800x800')
app.title("TTF Data Files")
app.configure(bg='#263D42')


#Functions
def open_File():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("Data files","*.dat"),("all files","*.*")))

def display_file():

    skipcnt = 0
    with open(filename) as f:  # auto closes after loop
        for row in f:
        skipcnt += 1
        if "Tension" in row and "Elong" in row:  # top of header
        break;
    
    skipcnt += 3  # skip headers
    
    df = pd.read_csv(myfile, skiprows=skipcnt , delimiter='\t')    
    

textArea = tk.Text(app, height=45, width=100, wrap=tk.WORD)
textArea.pack(expand=True)

#Buttons!
button = tk.Button(app, text = "Open File", command=open_File)
button.pack()

button = tk.Button(app, text = "Display File", command=display_file)
button.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It yells about indentation because your for-loop and if-statement are not indented:

```
def display_file():
    skipcnt = 0
    with open(filename) as f:  # auto closes after loop
        for row in f:
            skipcnt += 1
            if "Tension" in row and "Elong" in row:  # top of header
                break; 
    skipcnt += 3  # skip headers
    df = pd.read_csv(myfile, skiprows=skipcnt , delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: Well alright then. I guess Python is super anal about its indentations. Still learning this stuff, but thank you, that makes more sense now as I see as its "supposed" to look in form and flow.  I'm coming from Vb.net so its a slight change as spacing was automatic.

Comment: No problem! Python is a bit to get used to if you come from another language but I find it very powerfull in its own way. Just learn about the quirks and you'll be good to go ;) PS. don't forget to mark it as the answer if it answered your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that part of your code isn't indented properly.
This part

```py
    with open(filename) as f:  # auto closes after loop
        for row in f:
        skipcnt += 1
        if "Tension" in row and "Elong" in row:  # top of header
        break;
```

has a for loop where nothing in the for loop is indented.
Corrected, it would look like this

```py
    with open(filename) as f:  # auto closes after loop
        for row in f:
            skipcnt += 1
            if "Tension" in row and "Elong" in row:  # top of header
                break
```